# Jquery mobile hide button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile website in MVC4/C# and am using a wizard to do some data-input (http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx) I'm also using jQuery v1.8 and jQuery mobile 1.3.1.

for some reason I can't get the 'back' button to hide() when initialy showing step 1, moving forward to step2 and back to step1 DOES hide the back button, using this code :

```
$("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
```

when I use the exact same code in $document.ready (or before setting the event-handlers) it doesn't hide the button on the initial view of the page / step.

the script code is loaded from a seperate file, loading the script code happens at the bottom of the cshtml file.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Wizard.js"></script>
```

I'm just wondering what I have to do to get this working, I've searched here and tried various things like $(#back-step").hide$ for hours now, but I can't get it to work correctly. I have put some 'alerts' in my code below to see if the code is 'hit' and it is, so it's beyond me why the button isn't hidden.

hope someone here can help, I've included the javascript here below.

here's the wizard javascript code:

```
$(function () {

$(".wizard-step:first").show();             // show first step

$("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
alert('hide! first');

// attach nextStep button handler       
$("#next-step").click(function () {
    var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step

    var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
    var anyError = false;
    $step.find("input").each(function () {
        if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
            anyError = true;
        }

    });

    if (anyError)
        return false; // exit if any error found

    if ($step.next().hasClass("confirm")) { // is it confirmation?

        try {
            $("form").submit();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.name + ": " + e.message + " " + e.description);
        }
    }

    if ($step.next().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // is there any next step?
        $step.hide().next().fadeIn();  // show it and hide current step
        $("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').show();
    }
    else { // this is last step, submit form
        $("form").submit();
    }
});


// attach backStep button handler
// hide on first step
$("#back-step").click(function () {
    var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step
    if ($step.prev().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // is there any previous step?
        $step.hide().prev().fadeIn();  // show it and hide current step

        // disable backstep button?
        if (!$step.prev().prev().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // $step.prev().prev() == $(".wizard-step:first")) {
            $("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#back-step").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
    alert('hide! in ready');
});
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide your html?

Comment: Replace `$(function () {` with `$(document).on('pagebeforeahow', function () {` also you can use `pageinit`. Edit: I recommend using jquery 1.9

Comment: @Omar, thanks for your suggestion, the $(document).on('pagebeforeshow' dit the trick !!!

Comment: @Jeandre, the problem was solved (see previous comment) would you still like me to provide html ?